# custom toolbar layout alignment

Tags: android, xml, layout, alignment

I have created a custom toolbar with two images (icons). How do I get icons to align right please? android:gravity="end"  doesnt seem to do anything.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/my_action_bar_toolbar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:elevation="4dp"
 >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/help"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_qm"
android:gravity="end" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
android:gravity="end />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about having Linearlayout as direct child? and having the views in linearlayoyt.